# List directory contents asynchronously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I encountered the following code sample from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryEntry/createReader):

```
function readDirectory(directory) {
  let dirReader = directory.createReader();
  let entries = [];

  let getEntries = function() {
    dirReader.readEntries(function(results) {
      if (results.length) {
        entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
        getEntries();
      }
    }, function(error) {
      /* handle error -- error is a FileError object */
    });
  };

  getEntries();
  return entries;
}
```

How should this code work? the callback function passed to `readEntries` is called asynchronously so doesn't the `readDirectory` function already returns before the callback executes and fills the entries?

**EDIT:**

I tested it in Chrome and indeed it is asynchronous and the function returns without the entries filled yet. 
what I'm trying to achieve is to read a folder contents when a user drags and drop a folder into a website. I'm listening to 'drop' event, but the 'drop' callback returns before I even list the directory contents with the above code, and the dataTransfer object is destroyed.

How websites (such as OneDrive) handle drop of a folder?

Comment: Seems like getEntries is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if `readEntries` is async, `readDirectory` must be async too. I searched Mozilla, it's not documented yet, the async/sync property.